# Create a comparison list from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a list comparison and I feel like I`ve run out of possible approaches. This is the situation:
I have two lists, for example:

```
[00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
```

And:

```
[22, 55]
```

What I need is to construct a comparison list from those two looking like this:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Where 1 is put if an element is in a list and 0 is put if there is no such element. A comparison list should be ordered. I can`t find a clue for the correct approach here, so I am asking for an assistance.

Comment: Can you show what approaches you have tried? Are the lists guaranteed to be sorted?

Answer (score 5):

Using a `list comprehension`.

**Demo:**

```
l1 = [00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
l2 = [22, 55]
print([1 if i in l2 else 0 for i in l1])
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another list-comprehension that is a bit more compact:

```
l1 = [00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
l2 = [22, 55]

res = [int(i in l2) for i in l1]
```

which also returns the desired:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

---

> **Note:**
>
> `int(True) == 1` *and* `int(False) == 0`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `map`:

```
d = [00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55]
s = [22, 55] 
new_d = list(map(lambda x:int(x in s), d))
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```